# Pygtk client app

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want to create a client frontend in pygtk for my Django project. My general idea is to have one main window, and everytime the user has an action that must change the screen to unload previous widgets and load the new ones. E.g if i have a login page, after user logs in he is presented with a customer screen. I want the new screen to be placed on the same main window, kinda like a page stack, but without the "back" functionality. My first thought was to create a function for every screen, a show_login, a show_customers_screen, etc. Is this a good choice or should i try a better one. And a second question, related to the first. Can i create callbacks inside a function?

e.g

```
This would be a method of MainWindow
def create_login(self):
    ....creating widgets here
    #UnboundLocalError: local variable 'clear_clb' referenced before assignment
    btnlogin.connect('clicked', clear_clb, data=None)


    def clear_clb(widget, data=None):
          ..log in process
```

I know why i get the error. The thing is that the fields i want this func to clear are local in create_login. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Define the `clear_clb` symbol before referencing it:

```
def create_login(self):
    # create widgets
    def clear_clb(widget, data=None):
        # log in process
    btnlogin.connect('clicked', clear_clb, data=None)
```

However, the more usual, and in my opinion more readable, way of doing this is to save references to your widgets as attributes of `self`:

```
def create_login(self):
    # create widgets
    self.btnlogin = gtk.Button(...
    self.btnlogin.connect('clicked', clear_clb)

def clear_clb(self, widget, data=None):
    # log in process
```

Comment: so i must make all "screens" and its widget childs as MainWindows properties as to achieve what i want?

Comment: All the widgets that you plan on using later, yes. You can use the upper method if you don't want to do that.